# Iterate a RDD and according to one value to search in another RDD by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Actually I have two RDDs with the same structure `[(String, (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], Double))]`

rdd1

```
(A,(1,Map(VVV -> 1),0.0))
(B,(26,Map(DDD -> 2, PPP -> 7, OOO -> 2, EEE -> 3, LLL -> 12),1.35))
(C,(2,Map(VVV -> 2),0.0))
```

rdd2

```
(OOO,(2,Map(B -> 2),0.0))
(DDD,(2,Map(B -> 2),0.0))
(PPP,(7,Map(B -> 7),0.0))
(LLL,(12,Map(B -> 12),0.0))
(VVV,(3,Map(C -> 2, A -> 1),0.63))
(EEE,(3,Map(B -> 3),0.0))
```

And I need iterate `rdd1` and for each map key `((VVV), (DDD, PPP, OOO, EEE, LLL), (VVV))` to search in `rdd2` for its key, and after that call a function to perform a calculation.

What is the way to do that? Is that possible? Iterate a RDD and according to one value to search in another RDD by key.

I tested using:

```
def calculate(t: String, c: Int, m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], e: Double, r: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int], Double))]) = {    
    Tuple5(t,c,m,e,r.lookup("DDD"))
}
val newRDD = rdd1.map(f => calculate(f._1, f._2._1, f._2._2, f._2._3, rdd2))
```

And when I execute `newRDD.take(10).foreach(println(_))`

It gives me the following error message:

```
14/11/10 13:30:46 ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 54 scala.MatchError: null 
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.lookup(PairRDDFunctions.scala:572)
```

And another test was with:

```
rdd1.foreach(a => { rdd2.foreach(b => { println(b)}) })
```

But it gives me the following error message:

```
14/11/10 13:35:23 ERROR Executor: Exception in task ID 55 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:715)
```

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because RDDs cannot be used in closures like this `rdd1.foreach(a => { rdd2.foreach(b => { println(b)}) })` you need to express your computations in terms of operations on RDDs, not "with" RDDs. Think of RDDs as 'pointers'  to a distributed collection, not as the collection itself. The answer provided shows a way to work around the issue, I just wanted to point out the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would turn your maps into tuples (giving an RDD with one entry for each map entry in the original `rdd1`), and then join:

```
val splitRdd1: RDD[(String, (String, Int, Int, Double))] =
  rdd1.flatMap {case (s, (i, map, d)) => map.toList.map {
    case (k, v) => (k, (s, i, v, d))
    }
  }
val newRdd = splitRdd1.join(rdd2).map{...}
```

Comment: Nice idea!!!. I had not thought of that. I was thinking to do an union... Really thanks!